# JavaFX8 Timeline to scroll Grid of Circle Objects?

Tags: javafx-8, timeline

Using JavaFX8 and JDK 1.8.0_74 in IntelliJ, I created a basic pixel editor app.  I have two windows(stages).  One is a 32x128 matrix of Circle Objects placed in a Grid Pane and the other, a Tools widow; I have one Controller.java.  Using the mouse, the Tools window provides tools to draw lines, rectangles, etc. and a menu for Setup, Files and Playlists.  The Files menu presents the user with Open, SaveAs and Delete.  To view a saved pixel art file, the user clicks Open and via the FileChooser, the selected file is opened and each Circle’s color property is displayed.  The saved pixel art File can be sent via Wi-Fi to an RGB LED matrix that’s also 32x128.

To view pics and video go to:   https://virtualartsite.wordpress.com/

I can scroll a displayed pixel art file left, right, up or dow using Timeline.  However, I would also like to wrap the pixel image but have failed to eliminate small anomalies that appear at the beginning of the wrap while the remaining 95% of the wrap is correct?

The critical code for class WrapLeft is as follows:

```
  public static void runAnimation() {
        timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), event -> {
                    wrapFileLeft(pixelArray);
            }));

    timeline.setCycleCount(100);
    timeline.play();
  }   

  public static  void wrapFileLeft(Circle[][] pixelArray){

    // save pixelArray[r][0] in pixelArrayTmp[r][0] and wrap to end, pixelArray[r][col-1]

    Circle[] pixelArrayTmp = new Circle[row];

    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        pixelArrayTmp[r] = pixelArray[r][0];
    }

    // move all the pixelArray columns one column to the left

    for (int c = 0; c < col-1; c++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
            Color color = (Color) pixelArray[r][c+1].getFill();
            pixelArray[r][c].setFill(color);
        }
    }

    // move the pixelArrayTmp[r][0] column into the new, blank, end column of pixelArray[r][col-1]

    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        Color color = (Color) pixelArrayTmp[r].getFill();
        pixelArray[r][col-1].setFill(color);
    }  } }
```

The logic is to temporarily save column 0, shift all the remaining columns to the left one position and replace column 127 with column 0.  This is all done in one CycleCount(). The anomalies occur in the first four shifts left; the Circle Objects with colors other than black get changed to an adjacent color.  But after four shifts, all remaining shifts appear to be correct?

My best guess is the logical order of execution gets out of order because I not using Timeline properly or trying to execute too much in a single KeyFrame?  Increasing the duration doesn’t seem to affect the anomalies.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, your solution is wrong, you are storing referencing to circles in a temporary array, then changing the fill of the referenced circles, then using the updated referenced fill to set the new fill.

Instead of storing references to circles, store the fill values themselves.

```
public void wrapItLeft(Circle[][] pixelArray){
    // save pixelArray[r][0] in pixelArrayTmp[r][0] and wrap to end, pixelArray[r][col-1]
    Paint[] pixelArrayTmp = new Paint[N_ROWS];
    for (int r = 0; r < N_ROWS; r++) {
        pixelArrayTmp[r] = pixelArray[r][0].getFill();
    }

    // move all the pixelArray columns one column to the left
    for (int c = 0; c < N_COLS-1; c++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < N_ROWS; r++) {
            Color color = (Color) pixelArray[r][c+1].getFill();
            pixelArray[r][c].setFill(color);
        }
    }

    // move the pixelArrayTmp[r][0] column into the new, blank, end column of pixelArray[r][col-1]
    for (int r = 0; r < N_ROWS; r++) {
        pixelArray[r][N_COLS-1].setFill(pixelArrayTmp[r]);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your fix worked the first time I made the proper changes.  This the third time you have provided me with a most excellent answer that includes an explanation with code.  After spending hours trying to understand the problem and failing, your answer makes my day!  THANKS.